# Typo3 Fluid Image crop of with and height failure

Tags: html, typo3, crop, fluid

Using this code:

```
<f:image src="/uploads/extkey/{image}" alt="" width="115c" height="70c" />
```

Produces following HTML output:

```
<img src="typo3temp/_processed_/csm_testimage_31f6051846.gif" width="115" height="92" alt="">
```

[image: screenshot of image tag]

The image has a wrong height now and there are white bars at top and bottom. I figured out that "92" comes from its proportion (original image is: 1280 × 1024). I guess if the white bars at top and bottom are cut out the height of 70 will be reached. Any ideas why Typo3 is doing that wrong and does some others here having the same problem?

Using Typo3 6.1.5
ImageMagick 6

**EDIT #2:**
Tried different combinations with width,height,crop,maxWidth,maxHeight like:

```
<f:image src="/uploads/extkey/{image}" alt="" width="115" height="70c" maxHeight="70" />
```

The results/fails are:

- Image is not 115x70
- Image is deformed

Comment: Which library do you use (GM or IM6) for image processing? Do you get the same result cropping a JPG file or does it only happen with a GIF file? If so, is it a transparent GIF? Does anything change when it's not a transparent GIF?

Comment: happens to all type of images no matter with or without transparency

Comment: Please try if cropscaling using TypoScript works. Just try using an IMAGE object with file.width = 115 and file.height = 70c.

Comment: @ggzone Have you tried adding maxHeight attribute? `maxHeight="70"`

Comment: @Kamil changes nothing :( its totally ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the correct solution for this Bug. Its now more then 4 years old and still not fixed. The file and the line has changed to: /typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Imaging/GraphicalFunctions.php , Line: 2315

**http://forge.typo3.org/issues/19045**

t3lib/class.t3lib_stdgraphic.php
line 2181 (in version 4.2.6 that is)

adapt line to
$params .= ' -crop '.$data['origW'].'x'.$data['origH'].'+'.$offsetX.'+'.$offsetY.'! ';

I just added the "!" at the end and it now works - "!" after the crop command tells imagemagick to adjust canvas and viewport.

Didn't test this with any other installations than the one I'm working on right now (4.2.6 with IM 6.3.7), so somebody should probably do this before this fix is commited into core.

Answer (score 0):

The c after the dimension means "crop scaling". You cannot crop-scale for both width and height at the same time. So you should maybe set a fixed width (width="115") and then crop-scale the height (height="70c"). This way the image will be resized to width 115 pixel and every pixel that it's higher than 70 pixels will be cropped.

@ggzone: As I already commented, please try doing the same thing with a TypoScript object, meaning: Create an IMAGE cObject with the same parameters and output it on the page. If it doesn't work either, it's a problem of TYPO3 or ImageMagick, if it works, it's a Fluid problem. We need to narrow your problem.

Comment: the "funny" thing is, no matter if i put the "c" to the width or height the output for this image is 115x92 all the time if i dont change the values

Comment: the Typoscript Object thing works. Its a fluid problem it seems

Comment: "You cannot crop-scale for both width and height at the same time. " - sure you can!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to specify an box in which the image should be fit

i.e

```
<f:image src="/uploads/extkey/{image}" alt="" maxWidth="115c" maxHeight="70c" />
```