# typo3 fluid image viewhelper f:image: maxHeight / maxWidth 'c' command does not crop

Tags: fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I am having an issue with the image viewhelper through the [DCE extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dce) on typo3 6.2.

`<f:image src="{field.picture}" alt="" width="400" maxHeight="300c" />`

This is supposed to resize the image to 400px width and then crop the height to 300px according to the official documentation at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html

However what happens is that the image is referenced through the real path (`/fileadmin/some_folder/image.jpg`) instead of a cached / processed / cropped file (`fileadmin/_processed_/csm_more_garden_crop_e3ced4a9bb.jpg`). So there is no cropping at all.

How to reproduce:

install the `dce` extension, create a custom content element from the DCE menu, add a picture field and set the config to:

```
<config>
    <type>group</type>
    <internal_type>file</internal_type>
    <allowed>jpg,jpeg,png,gif</allowed>
    <size>0</size>
    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <maxitems>1</maxitems>
    <show_thumbs>0</show_thumbs>
</config>
```

then display the image in the template as

```
<f:image src="{field.picture}" alt="" width="400c" maxHeight="300" />
```

PS: There is an existing bug that might related to this however it's not being fixed and it's unclear whether this is the real cause: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/19045 (SO: [Typo3 Fluid Image crop of with and height failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161140/typo3-fluid-image-crop-of-with-and-height-failure) with no accepted solution)